# Since 22.04 Nautilus no longer Desktop link on the left

Tags: nautilus

One has an upgrade from 21.04 to 22.4 and the other has been freshly installed in 22.04. I want the freshly installed version to be the same with the link on the right.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a know bug in Wayland https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1985. Requires setting `gtk-shell-shows-desktop` on X11, but I haven't got gtk to read the setting in `~/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini`